# Swift iOS -How to Truncate Horizontal CollectionView Cells when they are about to go past Screen Bounds

Tags: ios, count, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview, uiscreen

I have a collectionView cell that displays the cells horizontally. I only want a set number of cells to show on the screen and after the amount I want to display `...` or something to signify there are more cells available. I don't want the user to scroll to more cells

Because there are different screen sizes like iPhone 4/5/6/7/iPad etc.. I don't want to put an exact number of items to get displayed. Instead I want to to truncate the amount of items based on the screen size for eg. On an iPhone 7+ in .compact size class  at least five cells can fit on the screen but on an iPhone 4 only three cells can fit on a screen and on an iPad  probably 20 cells.

I imagine I'd do something like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    //I know this is comparing an Int to a CGRect and it won't work
    if items.count > UIScreen.main.bounds.width{
         //stop count and display truncation dots ...
    }
    return self.items.count
}
```

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish that you need to implement the protocol method

```
collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                  layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
           sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

You need to manually return the size of each cell so in this case you will calculate the width of the cell depending on your screen size.

Comment: thanks I'll try it. How would I display the truncation dots ...? I was thinking maybe I have a specific cell t,with the dots already inside them and when the cells get close to the screen's bounds the truncated cell gets displayed last. Unless there is a better way?

Comment: Adding a comment to my response you will need to calculate in which screen you're to return the number of items in section you want depending on the screen and then add a last row the display the dots.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it